How to fix WhatsApp API Onboarding Failure Error?
Upon creating a new application on Meta for Developers and selecting the Business portfolio, I'm greeted with the unwelcome message: "Onboarding Failure. Please try again later or contact support to resolve the issue." This error halts my progress and prevents me from exploring the API's capabilities.
Onboarding failure
I sought assistance from both Official Support and the Stackoverflow community. To my dismay, I discovered that this issue wasn't limited to me. Numerous users worldwide had reported the same error for over a year, with no apparent resolution.
What further amplifies my frustration is the lack of concrete responses from the WhatsApp API team. It's ironic that after a grand global event, Meta Conversations 2024, promoting the API's features, I find myself unable to utilize it due to a persistent error.
Anyone else is facing this challenge, or better yet, has successfully overcome it?

I'm keen to know whether you managed to resolve this. If so, please tell us how you sorted it.

I managed to resolve it by activating two-factor authentication on my Facebook account.
